# What would you call 'A person who is ready for support all the time'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What would you call 'A person who is ready for support all the time'?

I wanted to write an email and convey to some clients that I will always be there for support, and was stuck when I got to this.

Comment: One common term for such a person is "Boy Scout," but I don't think you'd want to use it in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if that's *exactly* what you were looking for, but I would write something like

> Please do not hesitate to contact me again if you require further
>   assistance.

Comment: This implies a one-time response _("contact me again")_, not _"ready for support all the time"_.

Comment: Andrew, does "Please do not hesitate to contact me *any time* if you require further assistance" sound better to you?

Answer (score 4):

Though the term is rather casual, a **"go-to guy"** (or "go-to person") is someone who is continuously available for help and support in a professional environment.

Comment: I disagree.  A "go-to guy" (or "go-to person") is someone who will have the knowledge to help (with a given class of problems).  The terms say nothing about when that help's available.  See [Macmillan definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-to-guy) and examples of [usage in wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=%22go-to+guy%22&button=) and [Safire article](http://www.taipeitimes.com/News/editorials/archives/2005/05/08/2003253712).

Comment: "a person to whom one turns for help or support; also called go-to person" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/go-to+guy

Comment: I think the perceived conflict arises in that a person is normally the go-to guy in a particular area, rather than some sort of overall support system. Nonetheless, one *goes to* that person whenever a problem in his/her area arises, and the implication is that they'll be there to help with the problem. If your area is broad, your go-to status is broad, as well.

Comment: +1, It's implied that a *go-to person* is there when you need them.

Answer (score 3):

A generally acceptable phrase for this is **on-call**.

> I am available **on-call**.
>
> My contract includes 24/7 **on-call** technical support.
>
> I may have to leave early if my phone rings because I'm **on-call**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of support you are providing, some alternatives are more appropriate than others.

For generic "technical support", something like this can work: "I will provide technical support and operational assistance through the lifetime of the project. Don't hesistate to contact me with questions, problems, or concerns."

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster's and myself offer the following:

**Leech**:  a hanger-on who seeks advantage or gain

**Parasite**:  something that resembles a biological parasite in dependence on something else for existence or support without making a useful or adequate return

**Moocher**:  one who sponges, begs, or takes surreptitiously (steals)

**Deadbeat**:    one who persistently fails to pay personal debts or expenses

**A Drag**:  someone or something that makes action or progress slower or more difficult

Used in a sentence:  "Single motherhood is a breeding ground for parasites, leeches, moochers, deadbeats, and is a drag on society as a whole."

**Sorry.  I later saw the last 1/2 of your question.  My answer would not apply in your case.  However, I leave it for those who are not familiar with the other sense of the word.**

Related more to your question:

solid, dependable, reliable, a man.

Answer (score -2):

24h-support-man

(twenty four hours support man)

You can bring this concept to a real plane, with some humour, suggesting on your signature, for example, that you can be called anytime, anyday, 24 hours on day, 7 days on a week, even on weekends. This means full support to me. No lack. Specially if you really know they will never call you after friday 9:00 PM.

> Rohit McFlanders
>
> 889-7575 - supporting you 24/7.

or something near this.
uh.. a remider. Don't do this if you work with ad agencys or film production. They'll call. Probably on Saturday 12:00 AM.  :-/

Comment: "24/7 full supporting you" is not correct English.  A better tag line would be "supporting you 24/7."

Comment: @DeepYellow Thanks. Should you upvote now?

Answer (score -2):

1.1 yes-man, People pleaser, right-hand man,man friday,
1.2 do-gooder, Good Samaritan
1.3 aide, auxiliary

2.1 Glad to be your aide 24/7
2.2 Assuring you of my best support 24/7