# Better way of saying "Go-to man"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

Does anyone have a suggestion for a gender-neutral alternative to the phrase "Who's the go-to man?" *The go-to person* feels stylistically awkward.

Comment: What is a 'go to man'?

Comment: I'm assuming "go-to man" or "go-to guy". The person you go to when you have a requirement for a specific thing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I never heard of *"the go to man"* before, but Google Books suggests it's often hyphenated and/or quotated, so it should probably be treated as "idiomatic slang". Perhaps *"go-to guy"* would do, given *"guy"* is often gender-neutral these days. In context, a male or female could reasonably say ["I'm your huckleberry"](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/huckleberry), but I've never heard any other related constructions using the word *huckleberry*.

Comment: Also see peripherally-related [Is there a term I can use for a boss's favorite employee?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34238) and [What would you call a person who is ready for support all the time?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43694).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about, "who is the point person"?

Comment: Sometimes the person who is the "point person" is actually **not** your "go-to guy." Your go-to guy is the one who will know the answer and get whatever you're needing done done quickly and well. Sometimes the point person is not that guy.

Comment: @Brad, as good as your answer may have been, it's often best for the O.P. to wait a few hours – at least – before accepting an answer, just to see what other people might contribute or suggest.

Comment: @helen melichar: My understanding is that the point person (actually a point man) is the one who "leads a charge" in the military. Is this the sense you want?

Comment: The term point person, IMO, comes originally from the military term for the man in front -- the point man. However, in modern (BrE) business usage, it exactly conveys the sentiment that I inferred from the OP's question, namely that of being the person to whom queries of a particular ilk should be directed.

Answer (score 13):

What's wrong with "go-to person"?

I've heard "go-to guy" and "go-to girl". But that assumes you know which it is.

You could say "expert" or "authority" if that fits the context. Or "point of contact" might work.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, it is common business vernacular to refer to them as the *guru* of a particular subject.

Answer (score 4):

**Man**  *is* gender-neutral here, go ahead and use it for whoever it is.

'One small step ...' (Ok, that was capitalized); 'Man doesn't live by bread alone.' ...

If you change the wording, no one will understand the idiom.

Answer (score 3):

"Go to man" can mean a few things. If you are looking for a 'better" way to say it that is not ambiguous, here are some examples that define it:

- The most knowledgeable person about something
- The person who gets (these/those) things done
- The single point of contact who has authority to do something

Answer (score 3):

I've heard people just omit the "guy" or "gal" part and use "go-to" as a noun rather than an adjective, like this:

"Jane is our go-to for this sort of thing."

Answer (score 1):

Often in business, the perhaps aesthetically lacking term "subject matter expert" is used to refer to someone particularly proficient in an area.  For a more general term, one might use "fixer" (one who solves/fixes problems).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, how about "mainstay"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most appropriate word to use to describe a "go-to" person would be  **an authority**.  Not to mention, it's gender neutral.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same dilemma, and must disagree with some comments here. "Go-To Guy" doesn't work for a woman.  "Go-To Gal" was too old fashioned decades ago.  "Go-To Girl" is age inappropriate for most professional women.

How about "expert?"

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised that this hasn't been given but I hear **captain** used in almost every environment.

In sports the referees talk to the captain to discuss rulings.  Teammates talk to the captains about concerns or issues.

Captain signifies there is a team but it could be debate team or a team in the workplace.  I am begrudgingly a captain of our internal innovation team.  Which means when someone has an idea they come to me first.